# PHP - xml data from specified tags as sql entries

Tags: php, mysql, xml, export

I have XML file with some data. I need put into sql table data from this file but only from specified tags as separate mysql entry.

This is example of XML data

```
<entry>
    <published>2014-12-24T00:03:00.002-08:00</published>
    <updated>2014-12-24T00:04:26.884-08:00</updated>
    <title type='text'>Article title</title>
    <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind'/>
    <content type='html'>Here content data</content>
    <author>
        <name>Author name</name>
        <uri>http://www.example.com</uri>
        <email>some@email.com</email>
    </author>
    <thr:total>0</thr:total>
</entry>
```

Now i want take data from this tags and put to sql table as separate entry.
In MySQL i got table with 'date', 'title' and 'content' columns and only from this tags i need put data to mysql.

I just need to know how import data from XML and use in PHP. Nothing more.

Please share some tips for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize the xml_parse_into_struct() function, which will parse the data from your XML document into a usable PHP array.

```
<?php
$xmlfile = 'test.xml';
$xmlparser = xml_parser_create();

$fp = fopen($xmlfile, 'r');
$xmldata = fread($fp, 4096);

xml_parse_into_struct($xmlparser,$xmldata,$values);

xml_parser_free($xmlparser);
print_r($values);
?>
```

You will need to modify the code for your specific needs.

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_xml_parse_into_struct.asp

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what i need... print_r($values) don't print content of content tag. In my XML file in this tag i have encoded HTML data of article content. Also this function don't print everything from file, only very small part of entries.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right code for that what i need.

```
<?php 

$xmlurl = 'file.xml';

$dom = new DOMDocument();   
$dom->load($xmlurl);

$records = $dom->getElementsByTagName('entry');

foreach($records as $record) {

    $dates = $record-> getElementsByTagName('published');
    $date = $dates->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $date = strtotime($date);

    $titles = $record-> getElementsByTagName('title');
    $title = $titles->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $contents = $record-> getElementsByTagName('content');
    $content = $descs->item(0)->nodeValue;

    safe_query('INSERT INTO article (date,title,content) VALUES ("'.$date.'","'.$title.'","'.$content.'")');

}

?>
```